# MsSql Group or Order 2 different column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table like this;

```
   Product   Price  Type
-----------------------------------------
   TV          10    T1  
   Computer    15    T1
   Banana      2     T2
   Apple       3     T2
```

And I want to sort this two different types. (MS-SQL)

```
   Product   Price  Type
-----------------------------------------
   TV          10    **T1**  
   Banana      2     **T2**       
   Computer    15    **T1**
   Apple       3     **T2**
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM #tbl
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Price),
    Type
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/501599)</kbd>